# "System.NullReferenceException" for Using Session in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-variables

In My MVC project, I am using session values like

```
var empId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpId"].ToString());
```

I am getting Exception:

"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project.Web.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Have you checked Session["EmpId"] for null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs when you call a method on the null object. In your case the value of `Session["EmpId"]` is `NULL`.

Which means you are calling `NULL.ToString()`, which is invaild hence it throws error.

You can avoid the error using `null coaleascing` operator or simply check null before performing any opearation on it.

Solution:

```
if(Session["EmpId"] == null)
 //do something
else
 var empId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpId"].ToString());
```

Alternatively you can check my [blog post](http://karthikchintala.postach.io/system-nullreferenceexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-c) on it

Comment: I have the same issue but my property definition is like this get
            {
                if (Session["_exportViewModel1"] == null)
                    Session["_exportViewModel1"] = new BG.Indigo.Controls.Utilities.CountrySurveyReportExportVM();
                return (BG.Indigo.Controls.Utilities.CountrySurveyReportExportVM)Session["_exportViewModel1"];
            }
            set
            {
                    Session["_exportViewModel1"] = value;
            }

Answer (score 1):

Before use first check  is it null or not.

```
var empId = Session["EmapId"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmapId"]) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `null` as shown below :-

```
var empId = Convert.ToInt32((Session["EmpId"] ?? 0).ToString());
```

A more efficient way to accomplish your requirement :-

```
int temp = 0;
var empId = int.TryParse( Convert.ToString( Session["EmpId"] ),out temp );
```